# android - AAPT: error: resource not found

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I've recently make some changes in my app , weirdly I've got these errors since then and I've spend 2 days on it and I couldn't resolve it

I've checked every layout and drawable and images , nothing bad there .

this is the error I've and there are too many more of these :

```
app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:326:5-332:13: AAPT: error: resource drawable/btn_custom (aka com.xxxx.xxxx:drawable/btn_custom) not found.
```

this is the code in my style:

```
<style name="CustomBtn" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_custom</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
</style>
```

this is the btn_custom in my drawables :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

the file is exist in project and I've too many more of these .

what should I do ? how can I fix this ? I've cleaned the project , rebuild it , invalidate it , even copy the project and reopen it but not worked

can you help me  ? how to find out the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

the error suggest that btn_custom file is missing under res > drawable directory. please verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved your `btn_custom` drawable to some non-main [resource set](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) such as `xhdpi` or `v7`?

I suggest you copy the contents of the file and recreate it.

Comment: What does the v x.xx has to do with the question?

Comment: I accidently configured a resource for certain android version before, making it not findable for all version builds. thought it might be the case.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now, let me help make it clearer, feel free to revert my change if it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your file in the package directory in the Android Studio.

Go to Android Studio -> Click on the top left android dropdown button -> then select the packages -> In the packages section check the file in the all drawable folder section -> If your file found in another folder cut the file and paste to the drawable folder.

If these above steps not working change the file name, rebuild it, invalidate it.